# Find $P(X < Y)$ for $X$ uniform and $Y$ normal

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Suppose $X$ is uniform in $[0, 1]$ and $Y$ is $N(0, 1)$, and they are independent. Find $P(X < Y )$.

Here's my attempt:

So since they are independent, the joint distribution is $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 1\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}$ on $0 \leq x \leq 1$. So the answer should be the integral of the joint distribution over the area where $x < y$, which in this case is

$$\int_0^1\int_x^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}dydx$$

Is this correct? But if so, how do I evaluate this integral? Should I switch the order of integration? But in that case I would need two integrals, one for the case where $y < 1$ and another for $y > 1$. And the integral for the second case is still hard do calculate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that $$\begin{align*} \Pr[X < Y] &= 1 - \Pr[X \ge Y] \\ 
&= 1 - \left(\Pr[Y \le 0] + \int_{y=0}^1 \Pr[X > Y \mid Y = y]f_Y(y) \, dy \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} - \int_{y=0}^1 (1-y) \frac{e^{-y^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \, dy \\
&= \frac{1}{2} - \left( \Phi(1) - \Phi(0) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{y=0}^1 y e^{-y^2/2} \, dy \right) \\
&= 1 - \Phi(1) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \left[ -e^{-y^2/2} \right]_{y=0}^1 \\
&= 1 - \Phi(1) + \frac{1 - e^{-1/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \approx 0.315627
\end{align*}$$
where $\Phi(1) = \Pr[Y \le 1]$ is the CDF of the standard normal distribution at $1$.

---

If you have trouble following the above reasoning, we can still use your integral, which is correct:  $$\int_{x=0}^1 \int_{y=x}^\infty \frac{e^{-y^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \, dy \, dx = \int_{y=0}^1 \int_{x=0}^y \frac{e^{-y^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \, dx \, dy + \int_{y=1}^\infty \int_{x=0}^1 \frac{e^{-y^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \, dx \, dy.$$  All I have done here is interchanged the order of integration; in doing so, we must split the region of integration into a triangular piece and an infinite rectangular piece; i.e., $$(0 \le X \le 1) \cap (X < Y) \equiv (0 \le X \le Y \le 1) \cup (0 \le X \le 1 < Y).$$  The rest of the evaluation proceeds as follows:
$$\Pr[X < Y] = \int_{y=0}^1 \frac{ye^{-y^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \, dy + \int_{y=0}^1 \frac{e^{-y^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \, dy.$$  This is just the result of performing the inner integration with respect to $x$.  Now the first integral is simply $$\frac{1 - e^{-1/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}},$$ and the second is again $\Phi(1) - \Phi(0) = \Phi(1) - 1/2 = 1 - \Phi(1)$.

Comment: Can you explain the first three steps?

Comment: @b_pcakes The goal of the first step is to calculate the complementary probability.  The second is to condition on whether $Y$ is positive or nonnegative; if $Y \le 0$ then $Pr[X \ge Y] = 1$.  If $Y > 0$, then $\Pr[X \ge Y] = 1 - Y$.

Comment: Can you explain $1 - \Pr[X \ge Y] 
= 1 - \left(\Pr[Y \le 0] + \int_{y=0}^1 \Pr[X > Y \mid Y = y]f_Y(y) \, dy \right) 
= \frac{1}{2} - \int_{y=0}^1 (1-y) \frac{e^{-y^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \, dy$?I don't understand how you got those integrals

Comment: Look at how you could get $X \ge Y$:  if $Y \le 0$, then $X$ is always at least $Y$ since $X$ is uniform on $[0,1]$.  If $Y > 1$, then $\Pr[X \ge Y] = 0$ since $X$ cannot be greater than $1$.  If $Y$ is between $0$ and $1$, we just integrate the joint density for $0 \le Y \le 1$ and $X \ge Y$:  you can write it as $$\int_{y=0}^1 \int_{x=y}^1 \frac{e^{-y^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \, dx \, dy.$$ This is the same as $$\int_{y=0}^1 (1-y) \frac{e^{-y^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \, dy.$$